# Steam Web API: What is result of code with function GetAllItems?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I would like to ask about command *[GetAllItems](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamInventory#GetAllItems)* in steam api

What is result of mentioned code?

```
void SpaceWarItem::LoadInventory( IGameEngine *pGameEngine )
{
    SteamInventory()->GetAllItems( &s_RequestResult );
}
```

I didn't get it from the steam site.